# Frequency modulated voltage measurement with VFC voltage to frequency converter and counter

Tags: signal, voltage-measurement

I would like to measure the voltage across a nonlinear high voltage pulsed power circuit. The pulse is an underdamped RLC discharge but with some non linearity in the inductance. A  quarter cycle is on the order of $50 \mu s$. The rep rate is slow a few minutes in between pulses. I have fast counters (80Mhz) so I thought maybe I could use a voltage to frequency converter to convert the voltage to a frequency and then transmit this via fiber optics to my counter. What will limit my effective sampling rate? It seems like long before reaching the Nyquist frequency I will be limited by the settling time of VFC chips. 
VFC320 can output up to 1MHz and has a settling time of one pulse (\$1 \mu s\$) + \$50ns\$.
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbvs017a/sbvs017a.pdf
VFC110 can output up to 4MHz but has a settling time of one pulse (\$250 ns\$) + \$1 \mu s\$.
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbvs021a/sbvs021a.pdf

Do faster settling time VFC chips exist?
Are there other problems I should consider?

Comment: How wide is your pulse, how fast are its rising and falling edges, and what's its rep rate?

Comment: @EM Fields I added the pulse specs

Comment: I think the problem here is the question. You want to measure a voltage so show the circuit. Avoid phrases like "RLC discharge" - this means zilch. The fact that the inductor is non-linear is of no consequence to the question as far as I can tell. Also forget about how you think you might do it - this is just adding more confusion to the clever guy who can't be bothered to deal with bad ideas. So minimize the red herrings and you might get a decent answer. If you think I'm being harsh don't because I'm trying to help. If you still think I'm being harsh then sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are interested in reproducing fairly fast pulses, since you seem to need submicrosecond timing.

In this case, VFCs are not what you want. You've missed the fact that the output frequency is proportional to the input amplitude. Consequently, if you are set to measure a full-scale pulse with a 1 MHz output, a 10% of full scale pulse will only produce a 100 KHz output. It is possible to reproduce the shape of a waveform with VFCs, using a phase-locked loop as a receiver, but the response will be considerably slower than the carrier frequency (say, at least by a factor of 10). Using a counter to look at a VFC output will be even slower, since a counter will ordinarily produce a count totaled over some fairly large time interval. Or were you planning to do a cycle-by-cycle period measurement, followed by a 1/t conversion? If so, I don't think you can expect a counter to do that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing these difficulties out. I think instead of frequency modulation I should do amplitude modulation and acquire the signal with a digitizer.

Comment: You can do high-bandwith FM modulation of course, you just need an appropriate carrier frequency and wider modulator/demodulator bandwidth.  For example FM-modulated signals on analog satellite broadcast or Amateur bands have several MHz of information bandwidth.